# Как запустить animation навсегда?

Tags: jquery, css3, анимация, css

Привет всем, помогите запустить аниматион навсегда. :)

Мой код: http://codepen.io/DavidKern/pen/EavaYx

Спасибо. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример нужно немного подкорректировать.

В css, кроме `infinite`, нужно написать правильный `keyframes`, который зацикливает анимацию так, чтобы визуально было не видно, что запустился следующий цикл анимации:

```
.clace {
  stroke-dasharray: 2000;
  -webkit-animation: ane 9s linear infinite;
  -o-animation: ane 9s linear infinite;
  -moz-animation: ane 9s linear infinite;
  animation: ane 9s linear infinite; // Соответственно скорость анимации можно настроить изменяя количество секунд
}

@-webkit-keyframes ane {
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -2000;
  }
}

@keyframes ane { // Не забываем про браузеры кроме webkit
  from {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  }
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: -2000;
  }
}
```

Вынести стили фона из css в svg, думаю, так будет правильнее.

```
<g transform="translate(0.000000,500.000000) scale(0.100000,-0.100000)" fill="#ffffff" stroke="#000000" stroke-width="5"></g>
```

[Поправленный пример](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/EavyLJ)

Answer (score 1):

В стилях прописываем:

```
animation-iteration-count:infinite;
```